# Gradle: Unable to get plugin class in scope in build script

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I've been creating my own gradle plugin for the last few days (partly for learning, and partly to clean up some gradle build scripts I have laying around), however I've run into a problem that I can't figure out how to fix. In my plugin jar there is an interface named `me.alxandr.gradle.bintray.maven.MavenPackage`, yet when I try to import it I get an error saying that it can't be found. This is really weird, because the plugin is obviously running (I'm seeing output from it, and it's tasks are registering).

Currently I've done a hack to get around this as following:

```
project.ext.MavenPackage = MavenPackage
```

This just makes `MavenPackage` an available name in the buildscript, which works, but I loose any editor support for it cause it's entirely dynamic. Is there any way I can (from my plugin) get the buildscript to import a package when it's applied? Like how `MavenPublication` is in scope without me needing to import it. If not, why can I not import classes from my plugin package?

The entire source code is available at https://github.com/Alxandr/gradle-utils. You can see an attempted here: https://github.com/Alxandr/gradle-utils/blob/master/gradle/publish.gradle#L1. The current code works as is (with the hack explained above), but I'm just looking for a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a class from your plugin in your Gradle script, you must add the plugin JAR to the *buildscript* *classpath*.

Here's how to do just that:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { /* where to get your plugin jar from, e.g. mavenLocal() */ }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'some_group:me.alxandr.plugin:1.0.0'
    }
}
import me.alxandr.gradle.bintray.maven.MavenPackage
```

You can find more information in the Gradle User Guide about [using external dependencies in your build script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies)

Comment: Well, you are sort of write and sort of wrong. The plugin is obviously in my classpath somewhere as it is running (as explained in my question). Though I was told [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/unable-to-get-plugin-class-in-scope-in-build-script/20145) that each script has it's own classpath (when you do `apply from: 'somefile.gradle'`), so I need to add it to *that* classpath.